# Dúvida com Ponteiro para Struct em C

Tags: c

Estou tentando resolver um exercicio para a faculdade, onde o enunciado solicita que eu receba um registro, com dois campos como dados de entrada.
Um campo vetor para armazenar nome e outro para armazenar matricula.
Devo também declarar um ponteiro para a estrutura de dados heterogenea, e utilizar este ponteiro no momento da leitura de dados e da impressão dos dados na tela.

O meu código não apresenta erro no Visual Studio, porém quando abre o prompt de comando ele me gera a mensagem de erro :

[image: Erro]

Segue meu código :

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
//Programa Principal


struct cadastro {//Declaração da struct para armazenamento de registro com 2 campos
    char nome[40];
    int ru;
};
struct cadastro aluno, *pont1;//variavel aluno referenciando a struct

int main() {
    //Titulo do programa
    printf("---------Cadastro de aluno----------\n");
    printf("\n");

                          //Entrada de informações pelo usuário
    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    fflush(stdin);//Limpa dados armazenados na memória
    fgets((*pont1).nome, 40, stdin);//Referencia onde na struct deve ser armazenada a informação
    printf("\n");


    printf("Digite seu RU: ");
    scanf_s("%d", (*pont1).ru);
    //Print de dados informados pelo usuário
    printf("\n");
    printf("---------Dados Informados-----------\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("O nome digitado foi: %s\n", (*pont1).nome);
    printf("\n");
    printf("O RU digitado foi: %d\n", (*pont1).ru);
    printf("\n");
    //Fim do programa
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Em todos os lugares que pesquisei, vi a utilização de ponteiros para valores pré definidos dentro do código, porém, estou tentando fazer a mesma função ser executada com o input de informação pelo usuário.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você precisa allocar memória para a estrutura. No caso, você está apontando pra nada válido. Faça na inicialização algo como `pont1 = malloc(sizeof cadastro);`. Não esqueça de dar `free(pont1)` ao final. E leia sobre _alocação de memória_.

Comment: Lembre-se que você pode marcar uma como resposta correta. Se não sabe como, veja  aqui no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e já aprenda um pouco mais sobre a stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa alocar memória para seu ponteiro. Do jeito que utilizou, você está apontando pra nenhum lugar válido. Com o uso da função `malloc` nós alocamos um espaço na memória para você utilizar.

```
struct cadastro *pont1;// Ponteiro de cadastro

int main() {
    //Titulo do programa
    printf("---------Cadastro de aluno----------\n");
    printf("\n");

    // Aqui você está alocando memória para o cadastro
    // A partir deste momento, um espaço na memória é reservado para a sua estrutura
    // Como pode ver, o malloc aceita como argumento o tamanho, por isso, foi utilizado sizeof
    // Assim alocamos o espaço necessário para a estrutura
    pont1 = (cadastro*)malloc(sizeof cadastro);

    // Se quisesse alocar espaço para vários cadastros, multiplique pela quantidade
    //pont1 = (cadastro*)malloc(sizeof cadastro * QUANTIDADE);
    // E voCê pode acessar assim:
    // pont1[indice].nome = "Meu nome";

    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    fflush(stdin);

    // Você não precisa fazer (*pont1), você pode usar simplesmente pont1->
    fgets(pont1->nome, 40, stdin);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Digite seu RU: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &pont1->ru);

    //Print de dados informados pelo usuário
    printf("\n");
    printf("---------Dados Informados-----------\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("O nome digitado foi: %s\n", pont1->nome);
    printf("\n");
    printf("O RU digitado foi: %d\n", pont1->ru);
    printf("\n");

    system("pause");

    free(pont1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comentei o código com informações pertinentes

Comment: entendi agora. Todos os tutoriais de alocação dinamica que eu estava vendo estavam me confundindo mais, da forma como você colocou eu entendi. Independente então da quantidade de variaveis que minha struct tiver, eu poderei allocar a memória referenciando o malloc pelo argumento de tamanho da struct ? Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Importante é você lembrar também da função `free` que vai liberar os recursos alocados por você. Isto chama-se `memory leak`. Atente-se a conhecer bem isto também para não errar lá na frente. Se for uma aplicação maior em que é usado alocação dinâmica, fazendo a aplicação crescer em memória o tempo todo